# Pattern.Matches() does not work in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, pattern-matching

I am new to C# and Xamarin. I am working on Validation. I try to Validate the `EditText` in Android. So i am Validate using the `pattern.matches()` which is Android method.

and I use `using Java.Utils.Regex.Pattern` but the Compiler doesn't accept it and shows the following error:

> Error : Pattern is ambiguous refernce between `Android.OS.Pattern` and
>   `Java.Utils.Regex.Pattern`.

**Code :**

```
public static bool isValid(EditText edittext, string regex, string errMsg, bool required)
{
    string text = edittext.Text.ToString();
    edittext.Error = null;

    if (required && !hasText(edittext))
        return false;

    if (required && !Pattern.matches(regex, text))
        edittext.Error = "Is not valid";

    return true;
}
```

**Update :**

```
using Android.OS;
```

the above nameSpace is complesury require because Android is build in that namespace so it give error is I remove that namespace The `Bundle` give me error.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity_register);
}
```

and also

`using Java.Util.Regex.Pattern` is not import in Xamarin.

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Please share the full *relevant* code. I think you just need to provide a fully qualified name for the class you are using.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i update the question

Comment: Yes, so, try replacing  `Pattern` with `Java.Utils.Regex.Pattern` or `Android.OS.Pattern` and see if it works. Or, try replacing `!Pattern.matches(regex, text)` with `text.matches(regex)` (if the `text` is a java.lang.String)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i Update my question see..

Comment: You cannot add an import `using Java.Util.Regex.Pattern`. Did you try using the `if (required && !Java.Utils.Regex.Pattern.matches(regex, text))` instead of `if (required && !Pattern.matches(regex, text))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks that solve the Problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may provide a fully qualified name for the class you are using.

Use

```
if (required && !Java.Util.Regex.Pattern.Matches(regex, text))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
if (required && !Pattern.Matches(regex, text))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the full qualified name, you can also use this using

```cs
using Pattern = Java.Util.Regex.Pattern;
```

and then write

```cs
if (required && !Pattern.Matches(regex, text))
```